# Calculate the final position of a shape in OpenXML when embedded in a rotated group

Tags: rotation, powerpoint, openxml

I need to determine the position of images in `PPTX` (OpenXML `slideXX.xml`) files. We figured most of the things out (`a:off`, `a:chOff`, `a:chOff` and `a:chExt` are clear). If we have a document with all kinds of grouping in there, this works out nicely, and we can determine the exact position of each contained `"pic"`object.

However, we get into trouble when there is rotation involved (not the math to rotate a point around a center, that is checked and double checked). If only a single pic-node is rotated, it is easy, and we end up with the correct position and angle. However, when we start rotating groups, we have trouble to determine the correct positions.

Can someone point out the order in which we need to calculate the points, and which point we need to consider (`centers`, `(x,y)`)? Do we need to work from the top to the bottom (`group1 ->  group2 -> pic`) or bottom to top (`pic -> group2 -> group1`)? Do we flatten everything, how does the rotation work with the ungrouping/flattening?

My example is simple:

- a slide with 4 times the same image in it (to make it simple, each image `200x100` in size, lined up in a square of `400x200`, top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right)
- Rotate the `"bottom-right"` image `45` degrees, group it with the bottom-left image. Group the two top images as well, and finally group both groups together.
- Then, rotate the final group also `45` degrees (which makes the rotated image 90 degrees rotated, and the other three `45` degrees). [screenshot of the slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i1We.png)

I cannot find the correct order in which to work my way through the XML tree and in which order I need to apply the rotation.

Any help here would be appreciated: a good explanation, a clear example or a piece of (pseudo)-code) which points me in the correct direction.